# Jquery bootstrap scripting path update via javascript not working

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, routes, twig

I have a link in symfony2.0 generated with twig's path function like:

```
<a id="aBtn" href="{{ path("SomeController_someControllerAction",{'section_id':
    section_id, 'period_id': period.getId }) }}>A link</a>
```

And i also have some javascript that updates the "section_id" part of the generated URL every time a user changes a section on the page:

```
function updateSectionId(id){
  var aBtn = $("#aBtn");
  var href = aBtn.attr('href');
  var splitted = href.split("/");
  splitted[splitted.length-2] = id; //My routing puts the period_id at that position
  //(Yes i know its pretty hardcoded...)
  aBtn.attr('href',splitted.join("/"));
}
```

I have verified and the link is updated with the corresponding section_id.

However, debugging the action that recieves this request i find out that it *always* recieves section_id = 1.

```
public function newQuestionDialogAction($period_id, $section_id){
  //$period_id = 1 ALWAYS, regardless of href value on the link.
```

I am really clueless... am i missing something on twig's route generation?

EDIT: Here is route configuration

```
SomeController_someControllerAction:
    pattern: /{period_id}/section/{section_id}/someControllerAction
    defaults: { _controller: "SomeBundle:SomeController:someControllerAction" }
    requirements:
      _method: GET
```

EDIT2:
    I have a hunch that the origin of this problem is the jquery-bootstrap plugin "Modal 2" used to execute ajax requests to the server. I'll let you know if i find the problem. thanks!

https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-bootstrap-scripting

Comment: try `console.log`-ing the `aBtn.attr('href')` after you set it. Also, is `splitted.length-2` the correct array index?

Comment: Like i said, i verified the link before sending the request and it is updated correctly. I will check the console log.

Comment: How to uou define your route? Using annotations or YML? Anyhow, please update your question with route definition...

Comment: How do you submit? Do you just click on the link? If not, where's the code that triggers the request? Also, I think you want to use `prop` instead of `attr` but it shouldn't matter here I believe. I really don't believe this can be affected by that bootstrap script. Check also that you don't have 2 elements with id aBtn... that always causes borken stuff.

Comment: 1. I just click on that link, but modal2 plugin somehow catches that event and triggers the ajax request by itself. I think the plugin gets the href attribute on page load and saves it somewhere.

2. Tried with prop, didnt work

3. I only hawe 1 id="aBtn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was indeed with my javascript, and the solution is embarrassingly simple. I am posting here in case someone stumbles upon the same problem with the jquery bootstrap library.

Once you call

```
$(document).controls()
```

All the classes "open-dialog" on every element is removed, thus no matter how many times you call $(document).controls() it wont update the onClick event with the correct href. The workaround is to add "open-dialog" class before calling $(document).controls() again.

```
$("#some-element").addClass("open-dialog");
$(document).controls();
```

So, in my case, the solution was to update my updateSectionId method

```
function updateSectionId(id){
  var aBtn = $("#aBtn");
  var href = aBtn.attr('href');
  var splitted = href.split("/");
  splitted[splitted.length-2] = id; //My routing puts the period_id at that position
  //(Yes i know its pretty hardcoded...)
  aBtn.attr('href',splitted.join("/"));
  //Add open-dialog class and call controls to reattach the href
  aBtn.addClass("open-dialog");
  $(document).controls();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the link in your browser. Does it actually go to the new page with the correct ID? If not, you have an issue with your javascript.

Comment: Like i said, i verified the link before sending the request and it is updated correctly